# Funcion replace para espacios sobrantes en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-3.9

Hola buenas estaba realizando el siguiente codigo donde tengo que diseñar un procedimiento que elimine los espacios blancos sobrantes de una cadena de caracteres dada. Se considera espacio sobrante
cuando:
Existen espacios blancos al comenzar la cadena. En este caso
deben ser eliminados.
Existen dentro de la cadena más de un espacio en blanco
seguido. En este caso debe dejarse sólo un.
Existen espacios en blanco al final de la cadena. En este caso
deben ser eliminados.
El problema esta en que no puedo usar funciones definidas en python entonces tengo que predefinir una funcion para el replace() pero nose porque la funcion no me imprime la cadena.

```
def replace(a,b, Cadena):
    for i in range(len(Cadena)+1):
            letra = Cadena[i-1:i]
            if letra== a:
                Cadena = Cadena+b
            else:
                Cadena = a+Cadena[i-1:i]
    return Cadena              

Cadena = str(input("Ingrese una cadena: "))
a = " "
b = "  "

    for i in range(len(Cadena)):
        Cadena = replace(b,a, Cadena)
        
        
    if Cadena[0] == " ":
            
        Cadena = Cadena[1:(len(Cadena)+1)]
        
    if Cadena[(int(len(Cadena)-1))] == " ":
            
            Cadena = Cadena[:(len(Cadena)-1)]
    
    
    print("La nueva cadena es: " + str(Cadena)) #Salida
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
def elimina_espacios(texto):
    start = fin = 0
    for start in range(len(texto)):
        if texto[start] != ' ':
            break

    for fin in range(len(texto) - 1, 0, -1):
        if texto[fin] != ' ':
            break

    if start != fin:
        nuevo = [texto[i] for i in range(start, fin + 1) if texto[i] != ' ' or texto[i - 1] != ' ']
    else:
        nuevo = []

    return ''.join(nuevo)
```

Funciona así: primero recorremos el texto desde la izquierda saltando blancos. La variable `start` conserva el índice de ese elemento.

```
for start in range(len(texto)):
    if texto[start] != ' ':
        break
```

Y hacemos lo mismo desde la derecha, guardando en `fin` la posición del último elemento no espacio:

```
for fin in range(len(texto) - 1, 0, -1):
    if texto[fin] != ' ':
        break
```

Ahora que tengo las posiciones de inicio y fin del texto propiamente tal, hare una comprensión de lista, iterando sobre el indice de `texto` y produciendo la lista `nuevo`.

En cada iteración de la comprensión agrego un caracter a `nuevo` preguntado primero si es distinto de espacio.

```
if texto[i] !=  ' '
```

Si es espacio, lo aceptamos sólo si caracter anterior es distinto de espacio:

```
if texto[i] !=  ' ' or texto[i-1] != ' '
```

Como sabemos que el primer caracter en `nuevo` es distinto de espacio, no tendremos problemas con indices fuera de rango.

Sólo nos queda tratar el caso especial de la línea vacia (`""`).

Con una línea vacia, los dos primeros `for` no se ejecutan y las variables `start` y `fin` no se inicializan, por lo que debo hacerlo a mano al entrar en la función:

```
def elimina_espacios(texto):
    start = fin = 0
```

También debo agregar las líneas que sólo tienen espacios. En este caso, no puedo hacer la comprensión de lista:

```
if start != fin:
    nuevo = [texto[i] for i in range(start, fin + 1) if texto[i] !=  ' ' or texto[i-1] != ' ']
else:
    nuevo = []
```

Finalmente, convierto la lista y retorno una cadena:

```
return ''.join(nuevo)
```

#### Demo

```
def elimina_espacios(texto):
    start = fin = 0
    for start in range(len(texto)):
        if texto[start] != ' ':
            break

    for fin in range(len(texto) - 1, 0, -1):
        if texto[fin] != ' ':
            break

    if start != fin:
        nuevo = [texto[i] for i in range(start, fin + 1) if texto[i] !=  ' ' or texto[i-1] != ' ']
    else:
        nuevo = []

    return ''.join(nuevo)

tests = [
    "",
    "hola",
    "   El parrafo",
    "   El parrafo   ",
    "  a  b  c     d   "
]

for test in tests:
    print("->{}<-".format(test))
    print("->{}<-".format(elimina_espacios(test)))
    print()
```

produce:

```
-><-
-><-

->hola<-
->hola<-

->   El parrafo<-
->El parrafo<-

->   El parrafo   <-
->El parrafo<-

->  a  b  c     d   <-
->a b c d<-


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!