# Eliminar espacios sobrantes en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola buenas estaba realizando un código donde se pide construir un módulo que tenga como entrada una cadena de caracteres, y suprima todas las secuencias de espacios en blanco mayor
de 1. Por ejemplo, si la cadena original es:
(' ','a','h',' ',' ',' ','c'), la cadena resultante debe ser (' ','a','h',' ','c') (usar
variables de cadena distintas)
El codigo elimina los espacios pero me borra el ultimo carácter de cada oración.

```
def eliminar_espacios(Cadena):
        Cadenaresultante = ""
        for i in range(len(Cadena)):
            if Cadena[i-1:i]!=" ":
                Cadenaresultante = Cadenaresultante+Cadena[i-1:i]
            else:    
                if Cadena[i-2:i-1]!=" ":
                    Cadenaresultante = Cadenaresultante+Cadena[i-1:i]
        return (Cadenaresultante)

Cadena = str(input("Ingrese una cadena: "))
Nuevacadena = eliminar_espacios(Cadena)
print(Nuevacadena)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Funcion replace para espacios sobrantes en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489729/funcion-replace-para-espacios-sobrantes-en-python)

Comment: No es el mismo codigo porque tengo que eliminar los espacios del medio y no los iniciales o finales como el ejercicio anterior

Comment: Perdona, me acabo de dar cuenta. Elimino mi comentario.

Comment: Los espacios los elimina pero no me imprime el ultimo caracter de la cadena

Answer (score 0):

Buenas creo que solo poniendo en el bucle for +1:

```
for i in range(len(Cadena)+1):
```

De esta manera te cuenta el último elemento porque los elementos empiezan de 0.
quedando así:

```
def eliminar_espacios(Cadena):
    Cadenaresultante = ""
    for i in range(len(Cadena)+1):
        if Cadena[i-1:i]!=" ":
            Cadenaresultante = Cadenaresultante+Cadena[i-1:i]
        else:    
            if Cadena[i-2:i-1]!=" ":
                Cadenaresultante = Cadenaresultante+Cadena[i-1:i]
    return (Cadenaresultante)

Cadena = str(input("Ingrese una cadena: "))
Nuevacadena = eliminar_espacios(Cadena)
print(Nuevacadena)
```

Comment: Si, ya lo resolvi gracias!

Comment: ah , ok bueno me alegro. un saludo compañero