# Espacios sobrantes en un vector python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola estaba haciendo un codigo donde se pide construir un módulo que tenga como entrada un vector de caracteres, y suprima todas las secuencias de espacios en blanco mayor de 1. Por ejemplo, si el vector original es:
(' ','a','h',' ',' ',' ','c'), el vector resultante debe ser (' ','a','h',' ','c')
Las modificaciones se harán sobre el mismo vector de entrada y no se
podrán usar vectores auxiliares.
Nose porque no esta imprimiendo el vector sin los espacios, me sale la misma cadena que fue ingresada por el usuario.

```
def eliminar_espacios(Tamaño, Vectorcaracteres):
        for i in range(Tamaño):
            if Vectorcaracteres[i-1]== " " and Vectorcaracteres[i]==" ":
                Vectorcaracteres[i-1] = ""
        for i in range(Tamaño+1):
            
            print(Vectorcaracteres[i-1], end="")


Vectorcaracteres = []

Tamaño = int(input("Ingrese el tamaño de dicho vector: ")) #Entrada

for cont in range (0, Tamaño):
    Cadena = str(input("Ingrese una palabra: ")) #Entrada
    Vectorcaracteres.append(Cadena)

eliminar_espacios(Tamaño, Vectorcaracteres)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Funcion replace para espacios sobrantes en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489729/funcion-replace-para-espacios-sobrantes-en-python)

Answer (score 0):

Declaras una variable en donde vas a guardas palabras y la inicializas como un arreglo vacío

```
Vectorcaracteres = []
```

En seguida pides cuántas palabras serán ingresadas y con un ciclo vas pidiendo cada palabra por separado.
Y al final mandas llamar tu función `elimina_espacios`

```py
Tamaño = int(input("Ingrese el tamaño de dicho vector: ")) #Entrada

for cont in range (0, Tamaño):
    Cadena = str(input("Ingrese una palabra: ")) #Entrada
    Vectorcaracteres.append(Cadena)

eliminar_espacios(Tamaño, Vectorcaracteres)
```

```py
def eliminar_espacios(Tamaño, Vectorcaracteres):
        for i in range(Tamaño):
            if Vectorcaracteres[i-1]== " " and Vectorcaracteres[i]==" ":
                Vectorcaracteres[i-1] = ""
        for i in range(Tamaño+1):
            
            print(Vectorcaracteres[i-1], end="")
```

El problema es que en `eliminar_espacios` lo que haces es revisar si en `Vectorescaracteres[i]` hay un espacio vacío cuando en cada posición de ese arreglo tienes almacenada una palabra.

Si en `Vectorescaracteres` vas a tener almacenadas palabras completas puedes modificar tu función `eliminar_espacios` de esta forma:

```py
import re

def eliminar_espacios(Tamaño, Vectorcaracteres):
        for i in range(Tamaño):
            Vectorescaracteres[i] = re.sub('\s+',' ',Vectorescaracteres[i])
```

Si lo que vas a guardar en `Vectorcaracteres` son caracteres en cada posición, puedes hacer estos cambios.

```
import re

def eliminar_espacios(Tamaño, Vectorcaracteres):

    Vectorcaracteres = "".join(Vectorcaracteres)
    Vectorcaracteres = re.sub('\s+',' ',Vectorcaracteres)
    Vectorcaracteres = list(Vectorcaracteres)
    for i in range(Tamaño+1):
            
            print(Vectorcaracteres[i-1], end="")
```

Dado lo que comentas que no se te permite usar funciones definidas, se me ocurre que uses el método `pop()` que es un método de los tipos `List` al igual que `append()`.
El método recibe como parámetro un entero que es el índice del elemento a eliminar.

```
def eliminaEspacios():
    i = 0
    while (i<len(Vectorcaracteres)):
        if Vectorcaracteres[i] == " " and Vectorcaracteres[i+1] == " ":
            i -= 1
            Vectorcaracteres.pop(i+1)
        i +=1
    print(Vectorescaracteres)
```

Comment: Hay alguna manera de reemplazar la funcion re.sub()? dado que no nos dejan usar funciones definidas en python

Comment: @ValentinoPugliese Ya edité mi respuesta. Al final de esta pongo una solución con los requerimientos. Honestamente no se me ocurre como resolver esto haciendo las modificaciones sobre el mismo arreglo, sin uso de funciones definidas o arreglos auxiliares. Si tu docente les muestra como me avisas :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que los requisitos son:

- No crear listas auxiliares sino trabajar directamente con la suministrada
- No usar funciones de otros módulos como `re.sub()`, ni "funciones definidas" (no sé muy bien qué significa esto)

...está claro que hay que operar sobre la lista de modo que ésta al final quedará más corta de lo que estaba al principio. Es decir, hay que eliminar elementos de la lista.

Hay dos formas de hacer esto:

- Usar `lista.pop()` permite extraer un elemento (¿cuenta ésto como "función definida" que no debería usarse?)
- Usar asignación de *slices*, es decir, por ejemplo: `lista[3:6] = []` Eso reemplazará los elementos 3, 4, y 5 por "lista vacía", por lo que los eliminará.

Ya que ya existe una respuesta que usa el primer enfoque, en ésta voy a usar el segundo.

**Otra consideración**: eliminar elementos de una lista mientras se recorre ésta con un bucle `for` está abocado a problemas (por ejemplo,  si pones `for i in range(len(lista))`, `len(lista)` se evalúa sólo al inicio del bucle y no en cada iteración, y por tanto contiene el tamaño de la lista al principio, pero cuando ésta mengue se producirá un acceso a elementos más allá de su final). Por tanto sólo nos queda usar un bucle `while` y tener cuidado a la hora de incrementar el índice para que nunca se salga de los límites de la lista.

### Pseudocódigo

Con todas estas ideas en la cabeza, un enfoque podría ser:

- Iterar (con un `while`) sobre el índice `i` de la lista y cuando se encuentra un espacio, entonces:

  - Tomar nota del índice en que encontramos el espacio, e iterar en otro bucle interno (con otro `while`) mientras sigan existiendo espacios (o se llegue al final de la lista). Esto sirve para avanzar sobre una serie de espacios seguidos.
- Al salir del bucle interno estaremos en un carácter no-espacio.
- Reemplazamos el slice `[inicio:i]` con la lista `[" "]`, lo que reemplaza la secuencia de espacios por uno solo. Esto funciona incluso si la secuencia de espacios tenía un solo espacio, pues la deja como estaba.
- Reasignamos el índice de bucle `i` a la posición tras ese espacio (`inicio+1`).

### Código

```
def eliminar_espacios(v):
  # No necesitamos recibir el tamaño, pues sale de len(v)
  i=0
  while i < len(v):
    if v[i] == ' ':   # Encontramos un primer espacio
      inicio = i      # Tomamos nota de dónde

      # Avanzamos ahora sobre la secuencia de espacios
      while i < len(v) and v[i] == " ":
        i += 1
      # Al salir de la secuencia de espacios, la reemplazamos por uno solo
      v[inicio:i] = [' ']
      i = inicio + 1
    else:  # Si no era un espacio simplemente avanzamos al siguiente
      i += 1
```

**Demo**

```
vector = [' ','a','h',' ',' ',' ','c']
eliminar_espacios(vector)
print(vector)
```

---

```
[' ', 'a', 'h', ' ', 'c']
```

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Te la simplifico, tu función no elimina un elemento, lo que hace es que al encontrarse 2 espacios juntos, deja un elemento como vacío "".
Vos tenes que eliminar el elemento cada vez que te encontras con dicha condición.
Ahora bien, si vos estás recorriendo una lista con un bucle y le vas eliminando elementos en el proceso, te vas a encontrar con un error al final de la lista xq va a seguir buscando elementos que ya no existen porque tu lista se va acortando pero el bucle tiene una determinada cantidad de interacciones. Se puede solucionar de varias maneras pero yo te diría que coloques un try, y en caso de except un break y que el bucle sea un while para ir modificando su iterador sin problemas.

```
def eliminar_espacios(Vectorcaracteres):

    largo = len(Vectorcaracteres)
    i = 0
    while i < largo:
        # Siempre le sumamos 1 al iterador y evitamos que valga 0, porque sino compararía el primer caracter
            # con el último de la lista.
        i += 1
        try:
            # Concatenamos 2 elementos y los comparamos con 2 espacios juntos
            if (Vectorcaracteres[i-1]+Vectorcaracteres[i]) == "  ":
                
                # Eliminamos el elemento
                Vectorcaracteres.pop(i)

                # Esto hace que se vuelvan a revisar las mismas posiciones de caracteres, porque de lo contrario
                    # cada vez que vamos eliminando un elemento se avanza de a 2 posiciones
                i -= 1

        except:
            # Si estuvimos eliminando posiciones, seguramente se producirá una excepción cuando querramos ingresar
                # a una posición que no existe más, ya que el largo inicial de la cadena es distinto del resultante.
            break
    
    # Imprimimos la lista para ver los resultados
    print(Vectorcaracteres)

# Pedimos un texto al usuario y lo convertimos a lista, sino la impresión no nos mostrará con claridad los espacios
    # en blanco, ya que si es un string va a imprimir un string, un texto.
    # Además el método .pop sólo funciona en una lista y no en un string.
texto = list(input("dale:"))
eliminar_espacios(texto)
```